# SQL safety when storing data using WordPress built-in functions

Tags: wordpress, security, sql-injection

When I use WordPress built-in functions like

`add_post_meta, update_post_meta, add_user_meta, update_user_meta`

`wp_insert_post, wp_insert_user`

Should I do any escaping or sanitizing before passing the user-input data to these functions or these functions themselves do the trick?

[here in codex Action_Reference/save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Example) the data is passed to `update_post_meta` right out of the `$_POST`.

Answer (score 6):

meta values are sanitized using `sanitize_meta`, post content is sanitized through `wp_kses_post`, etc... You can safely assume that built-in functions are secure.

Comment: what about wp_insert_user? I`ve seen two tutorials that in them data is escaped before passed to this function.

Comment: Users are sanitized with `sanitize_user`, you can inspect what it does right here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L886

Comment: but these functions sanitize_meta, ... just apply_filters, and when i searched for add_filters, I found that variables with empty string default value are hooked to them, any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. The return of sanitization functions is indeed filterable, so in theory, security could be weakened through these filters. If there is no function hooked to the filter, sanitization will simply be carried out the WordPress way.

Comment: I think those functions just apply the filter nothing more:

function sanitize_meta( $meta_key, $meta_value, $meta_type ) {
 return apply_filters( "sanitize_{$meta_type}_meta_{$meta_key}", $meta_value, $meta_key, $meta_type );
}

Comment: You're right, that allows you to do some very specific filtering, if needed. As a rule of thumb, you should never trust user input. WP has a large arsenal of formatting functions available, you could use e.g. `sanitize_text_field` to sanitize user input to be stored as post meta: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field